# Email form after Paypal button is clicked

Tags: php, html, forms, email, paypal

I'm making a Paypal button for a booking feature on a website. The only problem is that Paypal will only accept 200 characters for each form. Any extras are not carried over. This would be no problem except I want my visitors to be able to give me a description of the booking which will probably run over 200 characters.

Is there a way I can either:

1) Send more than 200 characters over Paypal (don't think this is possible)

2) Send an email with the contents of this single form when the button is clicked.

Or if any of you have an alternative idea I'm all ears. If you can make things as simple as possible for me, I would really appreciate it. I only know HTML/CSS but I figure PHP is required here. If any of you can help me figure out that I would appreciate it too. If the form is emailed it won't need to be sent through Paypal, however both actions will need to take place when the user clicks the buy now button. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the form code:

```
    <form name="Booking" class="formoid-default" style="float:right;font-size:14px;font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue','Helvetica',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;color:#666666;width:480px" onSubmit="return validateForm()" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="MPNJK99ZNT994">
<table>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on0"value="Package">Packages & Addons</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Standard Rental">Standard Rental $199.00 USD</option>
    <option value="All In Special">All In Special $399.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Standard Rental + Custom Software Graphics">Standard Rental + Custom Software Graphics $149.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Standard Rental + Custom Frame Paint">Standard Rental + Custom Frame Paint $99.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Standard Rental + Custom Frame Decal">Standard Rental + Custom Frame Decal $99.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Reservation Date Deposit">Reservation Date Deposit $100.00 USD</option>
</select> </td>
 </tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Contact Name"><strong>Reservation date deposit</strong> ensures that your unit will be reserved for your specific date and time (units are limited). Your deposit will go towards your remaining balance due upon delivery. Please give us a call if you have any questions about reservation date deposit.<hr style="height:0px; visibility:hidden;" />Contact Name*</tr></td><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Contact Phone">Contact Phone*</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Address of event location">Address of event location*</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os3" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Start time for your rental">Start time for your rental*</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os4" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on5" value="Date of event">Date of event*</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="dp2" name="os5" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on6" value="Comments/Information">Comments/Information<br>Please provide us any information about the event. Theme, colors, name of person being celebrated, logo, etc. Keep in mind we use this information to design your custom software graphics and watermark. The more information the better.</td></tr><tr><td><textarea type="text" cols="20" rows="5" name="os6" maxlength="2000"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr class="pay"><td><input type="hidden" name="on7" value="How did you hear about us?">How did you hear about us?</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os7" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table><br>
<center>
<label for="disclaimer"> <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree_terms" id="disclaimer" />&nbsp;I accept all <a style="color:#3387D4;" href="terms_of_use.html" target="_blank">terms of use</a></label>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</center>
</form>
```

The second to last form is the one I am talking about. As you can see I have it set to max characters at 2000, but Papal only carries the first 200. validateForm() checks to make sure the required forms and terms of use are checked in case you were wondering.

Really appreciate any input at all. Thanks for reading / replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to have a PHP script that handles and redirecting to payment gateways, including PayPal.

Rather than using a hosted button you can use HTML forms that send details of a transaction to PayPal. You can also send POST requests to PayPal’s servers with the details as post data, which is my preferred method as it means variables like `business` aren’t in your client-side code and unable to be manipulated.

Given a simple form like this:

```
<form action="checkout.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My fabulous product" />
  <input type="submit" name="buy" />
</form>
```

Your **checkout.php** script could look like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    // merge other details PayPal needs
    $query_data = array(
        'amount' => 'COST OF ITEM',
        'business' => 'YOUR PAYPAL ADDRESS',
        'cmd' => '_xclick',
        'currency_code' => 'GBP',
        'item_number' => $_POST['item_number'],
        'item_name' => $_POST['item_name']
    );

    // redirect to PayPal
    header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/?' . http_build_query($query_data));
    exit;
}
```

This is just a sample, but you should get the picture.

In response to your *actual* question, if you employ the approach as above then in your checkout script you can then do whatever.

One approach would be to create an order record in your database (with a status of “unpaid”). This will give you an order ID which you can pass as the `custom` parameter to PayPal. At the same time, you can also send the contents of `$_POST['comments']` via email, but you’ll need to capture the user’s email address before re-directing to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the a script that sends you an email with the data, and then allows the buyer continue to PayPal to make the payment.  However, what I would do would be to have the form write the information to a database and then assign an order number/id or etc to the customer that gets carried over to PayPal when they make the purcahse.  Then after the payment completes, you can look up that order id on your system and see everything that the buyer entered.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this exact issue.

I stacked two 200 character form fields on top of each other, and labelled the second as "extra space". Then all the text will comes back tidy and complete from PayPal.  The traffic hasn't had any issues minus just a couple.

Comment: Please give code example of your solution and be more specific on the traffic issues.  The current answer is very unclear and I am downvoting until it improves.